# ASP.NET using JQuery Progress bar

Tags: asp.net

I have a question about how to use JQuery progress bar to wait until long process finished.

I have a web page with a button and when the user hits this button ,some operation on server occurred.  For example inserting records into DB like this:

```
Int32 val = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["PLCID"].ToString());
String _MachineName = String.Empty;
_MachineIP = String.Empty;
DBLayer.getMachineByPLCID(val, out _MachineName, out _MachineIP);
```

I need to show progress bar for the user and prevent him from taking any action till the process finished.

please help!

Comment: "prevent him from taking any action till the process finished" - Not possible.  The user can always reload, navigate away, close the browser, unplug the computer, be hit by a meteor, etc.

Comment: so i need just disable the button and redirect him to a success page for example after the processing finished

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to disable the button and make redirection after the processing has finished, you can use this sample:

- http://tpeczek.com/2010/07/reporting-server-side-operation.html

You just need to replace re-enabling the button with proper call to window.location.